# In express.js POST method not getting called

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to put up a simple form handling project. The post method is not getting called. There is no output from the post method. I do not understand why this is happening. What is the issue here? 
This is the code I'm using.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');

var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  nationality: String,
});
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('person');
});

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var personInfo = req.body; //Get the parsed information

  if (!personInfo.name || !personInfo.age || !personInfo.nationality) {
    res.render('show_message', {
      message: 'Sorry, you provided worng info',
      type: 'error',
    });
  } else {
    var newPerson = new Person({
      name: personInfo.name,
      age: personInfo.age,
      nationality: personInfo.nationality,
    });

    newPerson.save(function(err, Person) {
      if (err) res.render('show_message', { message: 'Database error', type: 'error' });
      else
        res.render('show_message', {
          message: 'New person added',
          type: 'success',
          person: personInfo,
        });
    });
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I would like to know how to fix this issue.
I tried putting a `console.log()` output to log if the post method is being called. But there was no output from it either.

Comment: can you add your request sample as well ?

Comment: how do you make the request ? do you use post man?

Comment: app.post in the code snippet is not being called.